# URL parameter lost after first form/model validation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a guid to be used as a parameter during the creation of a new user. The route for this is defined as following:

```
  match 'add_user/:guid', :to => 'users#new', :as => :add_user, :via => :get
```

The problem is that when validation fails (ie. empty first name, etc.), the 'new' method reloads without the appended guid as was the case on the first load.

The form reloads with the validation error and

```
/users
```

as the URL. The guid is lost.

**Is there a way to preserve the guid between the various requests that occurs as the user input is being validated?**

Answer (score 0):

How about making a hidden input with the guid? Or changing `action` POST path to be the same as GET and passing the guid in the URL again?

Comment: The guid is a hidden input,but I do not understand why after a validation failure, it decides to GET /users, since I specified render 'new' when save fails.

Comment: The POST goes to /users, and you're rendering `new` on POST's path.